Stop lwc timer when console tab changes
i have a lwc on record page which calculates how much time the tab is active and work is going on . when i am switching the tabs which are standard console tabs on Case object , i want timer should run for active tab  and for the previous tab the timer should stop. as of now my below code the timer is getting stopped for all the tabs.

Shifting to 2nd tab

Shifting back to first tab

It looks timer is called multiple times for the
i have used import tabFocusedChannel from   "@salesforce/messageChannel/lightning__tabFocused";
but here i am getting response
{
    "currentTabId": "ctab1",
    "previousTabId": "ctab0"
}

with this data how can i determine to stop the previous tab timer. Even if i use apex to store the time on an object and retreieve back on page load , how can i still stop the timer for previous one and start the timer for active tab.
below is the code i am using
    import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
    import userId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
    import { CurrentPageReference, NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
    import { MessageContext, subscribe, unsubscribe, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from "lightning/messageService";
    import tabFocusedChannel from "@salesforce/messageChannel/lightning__tabFocused";
    import tabRefreshedChannel from "@salesforce/messageChannel/lightning__tabRefreshed";
    
         subscription = null;
    @api recordId; // Record ID from the record page
    @track timerValue = 0; // The value to display on the page
    @track userId = userId;
    sessionTimer;
    timer;
    prevSession = 0;
    lastActivityTime;
    isTimerPaused = false;

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    subscribeToMessageChannel() {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                tabFocusedChannel,
                (message) => this.handleMessage(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );
        }
    }
    subscription1 = null
    subscribeToMessageChannel1() {
        if (!this.subscription1) {
            this.subscription1 = subscribe(
                this.messageContext,
                recordSelected,
                (message) => this.handleNewChannel(message),
                { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
            );
        }
    }


    connectedCallback() {
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel1()
        console.log("rec Id" + this.recordId);
    }

    currentTabId
    previousTabId
    handleMessage(message) {
        // console.log('@@@@ ' , message)
        // this.focusOut = true; 
       // alert(this.recordId)
        // this.stopTimer();
         console.log('@@@@ ' , message);
        this.currentTabId = message.currentTabId;//Create this property currentTabId 
        this.previousTabId = message.previousTabId;//Create this previousTabId
        //this.stopTimer();
        publish(this.messageContext, recordSelected, 
        {'tabId':this.currentTabId});
    }


 unsubscribeToMessageChannel() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription);
        this.subscription = null;
    }

    unsubscribeToMessageChannel1() {
        unsubscribe(this.subscription1);
        this.subscription1 = null;
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        alert('disconnected callback')
        this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();
        this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel1();
         this.stopTimer();
        this.removeActivityListeners();
    }

        handleNewChannel(message) {
            let focusedTabId = message.tabId;
            //If this tabId is same as the one sent in LMS
            if(focusedTabId  == this.currentTabId)
            {
                //Start the timer which would have stopped earlier, or is started 
                //first time.
                this.startTimer();  
            }
            else{//Call code to stop the timer as this is not the focused tab.
                this.stopTimer(); 
            }
    }


    startTimer() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            let currentTime = Date.now();
                    // Increment the timer value every second
                    this.timerValue++;
        }, 1000);
        }
    focusOut = false;
    setupActivityListeners() {
        ['click', 'mousemove', 'keypress', 'beforeunload','focus','blur'].forEach((eventType) => {
            //Use tab index to make sure ide time consider tab switching
            window.addEventListener(eventType, () => {

            });
        });


    }

    stopTimer(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }

    removeActivityListeners() {
        ['click', 'mousemove', 'keypress','blur'].forEach((eventType) => {
            window.removeEventListener(eventType, () => {
                // Listener removal logic
                console.log('#### ' , eventType)
            });
        });
    }

HTML
<template>
    <div style="background: white;padding: 20px;border-radius: 6px;">
        <div style="font-size: 30px;text-align:center; color:Blue;">{timerValue} sec</div> 
    </div>
</template>


What part of this isn't doing what you want it to do?  Where are you actually stuck?  Please edit your question with the details, or this is likely to get closed

hi Nick .. i have pasted one pic where u can see i have a timer run on record page .. now if users changes the tab to a different record , the previous timer is not getting stop . so where i am stuck is i want to stop previous timer and start the current focused page timer,

Here is the logic how you can achieve it:
Remove the startTimer from connectedCallback. We will call this later by adding 1 step in between.
Create a new LMS channel. The LWC component should subscribe to this channel.
In the callback handler for tabFocusedChannel or tabCreatedChannel event-in your case handleMessage- publish a message with payload as the currentTabId that you got already. Modified pseudo code for handleMessage:
handleMessage(message) {
  console.log('@@@@ ' , message);
  this.currentTabId = message.currentTabId;//Create this property currentTabId 
  this.previousTabId = message.previousTabId;//Create this previousTabId
  //this.stopTimer();
  publish(this.messageContext, NewMessageChannel, 
  {'tabId':this.currentTabId});
}

As the component has subscribed to this same LMS channel, it's subscribe handler will be evoked. Similarly, subscriber handler for LWC components in other console tabs will also be invoked.
The Subscribe handler should have logic something like this:
handleNewChannel(message) {
  let focusedTabId = message.tabId;
  //If this tabId is same as the one sent in LMS
  if(focusedTabId  == this.currentTabId)
  {
    //Start the timer which would have stopped earlier, or is started 
    //first time.
    this.starttimer();  
  }
  else{//Call code to stop the timer as this is not the focused tab.
    this.stoptimer(); 
  }
 }


Please note one scenario here:

If the 2nd tab is created/navigated first time: Component will be initialized and subscription handler will be called asynchronously. Hence, the code to publish our new LMS will have some latency, during which the timer in 1st tab will add few seconds before being stopped. As I could not find a console API event that is thrown when a tab focus is removed, we need to rely on focus event instead, which causes this small deviation. It will happen only when a tab is created.

hi @Sarang. I have updated my code. It seems its not working . When i am shifting from first tab to second one and again going back to the first tab, i am not sure the timer is running very fast. Can u please check

The timer is getting multiplied. on the tab shift i can see handleNewChannel() is getting called 5 times .

What i am seeing is handleMessage() which is tab_focused event is getting called 2 times , one for current situation before tab changes and 2nd time the tab has changed . This is making to call handleNewChannel() two times each

Did you remove the startTimer() form connectedcallback? I won't be able to help without seeing entire code and having a live debug. The code in my answer is just for explaining the logic, hence I am not sure if any other code in your component might be affecting this.

I see now that you have incorporated the changes. Could you check if stopTimer() is called when you go first time from 1st tab to 2nd tab? If not, then the whole logic will fail the way you mentioned. You can debug it from that point.
